# What is x86/mm?

Tags: linux, boot, x86

During boot time there are certain instructions run from something like
`x86/mm` as shown in the image. I was wondering if anyone knew what they were and is it a file system dependent instruction?[image]

Answer (score 4):

Those are messages from [the memory-management layer](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/mm/dump_pagetables.c?id=ed7588d5dc6f5e7202fb9bbeb14d94706ba225d7#n548). They’re not file system-related. “mm” in the kernel generally refers to memory management, and “x86” refers to the x86 architecture (which combines 32- and 64-bit support). The messages are architecture-specific (similar messages exist on ARM).